# Why some of my buttons not work correctly on html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to make some buttons to control some things in my canvas. I want them to appear in the right side of canvas, so i use css to style and move them. I also made a timer which stars when pressing the green button START and stops when pressing FINISH. My problem is that the first buttons do not work or pressed when i moved then in the right position. Do you have any idea why this happens?? Here is the part of my code that does what i am saying. Thank you in advance!!!

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FAFAD2";

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
})();

var startTime = Date.now();
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {
  var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
  t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 100);
}

function doTimer() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = 1;
    timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on = 0;
}

$('#start').on('click', function() {
  doTimer();
});

$('#finish').on('click', function() {
  stopCount();
});
```

```css
.timer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  left: 600px;
}

.both,
.one,
.two,
.timer {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
}

.both button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.one button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.two button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}

.timer button {
  background-color: #696969;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Simulation </title>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class='both'>
    <button type='button' id='start'>START</button>
    <button type='button' id='stop'>STOP</button>
  </div>
  <div class='one'>
    <button type='button' id='start1' style='background-color:#B22222;'>START 1</button>
    <button type='button' id='stop1' style='background-color:#B22222;'>STOP 1</button>
    <button type='button' id='position1' style='background-color:#B22222;'>POSITION 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class='two'>
    <button type='button' id='start2' style='background-color:#FFD700;'>START 2</button>
    <button type='button' id='stop2' style='background-color:#FFD700;'>STOP 2</button>
    <button type='button' id='position2' style='background-color:#FFD700;'>POSITION 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class='timer'>
    <span id="timer"></span> sec
    <button type='button' id='finish'>FINISH</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="455" height="650" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `timer_is_on` is not a `boolen` value.

Comment: @SalomonZhang But `0` is *falsy* and `1` is *truthy*. https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

try adding z-index to button wrapper and a position relative for canvas

`.both {z-index:99;}
 canvas{position:relative;z-index:10;}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to make it by replacing  `.both,
.one,
.two,
.timer {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
}` 
with `.both, .one, .two, .timer {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  float: right;
 }`

Comment: glad to know you fixed it using another solution

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because you're trying to set a timeout on a string, not a function:

```
function timedCount() {
  var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
  t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 100);
}
```

Change this line:

```
t = setTimeout(timedCount, 100);
```

And it should work.

Comment: You are right about this but my code did work and before! My problem is that when i moved the buttons on the right side the first ones cannot be pressed like they do when i have them above canvas.

Comment: @dim109 Then the problem is in your CSS - try adding or removing different rules and properties and see what happens

Comment: I thought that the problem might be in my CSS and i tried to change many rules but none of them worked for me! However i really thank you for your time and your answers!! :)